# Cell formula manipulation

Tags: vba

The formula expression of cells have structure similar to this:

```
    = A12 +B12- C1234 + E18 + CustomCellName1+D12 - H6- U8 - CustomCellName2 
+ CustomCellName3 + CustomCellName4- CustomCellName5 + G7
```

How can we scrub the variables with at most five characters such that the formula will be:

```
= CustomCellName1-CustomCellName2+CustomCellName3+CustomCellName4-CustomCellName5
```

Thanks

Comment: Will be a simple as those or can it be complex variations involving different Excel formulas. For example `Index(Match())` or `Sumproduct()` etc?

Comment: It is just as simple as literally eliminating the unwanted cell range/name from the expression

Answer (score 0):

> The formula expression of cells are of these forms:
> = A12 + B12 + C1234 + CustomCellName1 + CustomCellName3 + CustomCellName3

> Thanks but its either a + or - or a combination of both – John Snow 12 mins ago

If they are of this form then it is simple.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NewFormula As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to relevent sheet and range
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Ar = Split(ws.Range("A1").Formula)
    
    For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
        '~~> > 1 to preserve +
        If Len(Trim(Ar(i))) > 1 And Len(Ar(i)) < 6 Then Ar(i) = ""
    Next i
    
    NewFormula = Join(Ar, "")
    
    Do While InStr(1, NewFormula, "++") Or _
             InStr(1, NewFormula, "--") Or _
             InStr(1, NewFormula, "+-") Or _
             InStr(1, NewFormula, "-+")
        NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "++", "+")
        NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "+-", "-")
        NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "-+", "+")
        NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "--", "-")
    Loop
    
    NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "=+", "=")
    NewFormula = Replace(NewFormula, "=-", "=")
    
    Debug.Print NewFormula
    'ws.Range("A1").Formula = NewFormula
End Sub
```

But if they are not and involve operator other that "+" and also involve Excel Functions then it may not be easy.

Comment: Thanks but its either a + or - or a combination of both

Comment: I have updated the post. You may have to refresh the page to see it.